# Swift - Convenience initializer in subclass of CIDetector is not working

Tags: initialization, swift3

I don't understand why this does not work?

```
import CoreImage

class RectDetector: CIDetector {

    convenience init?(aspectRatio: Float) {
        let options: [String : Any] = [CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh,
                                       CIDetectorAspectRatio : NSNumber(value: aspectRatio)]
        self.init(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: options)
    }

}
```

I'm getting error **"Ambiguous reference to member `init(aspectRatio:)`"**.

If I try to add default value for aspect ratio like this:

```
import CoreImage

class RectDetector: CIDetector {

    convenience init?(aspectRatio: Float = 1.0) {
        let options: [String : Any] = [CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh,
                                       CIDetectorAspectRatio : NSNumber(value: aspectRatio)]
        self.init(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: options)
    }

}
```

then I get error **"Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"**.

Is this a bug? Why I can't subclass `CIDetector` with custom convenience initializer which is chaining to existing initializer?

P.S. I'm using Xcode 8.2 (8C38)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift imports some class methods as convenience initializers ([Class Factory Methods and Convenience Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID37)).

In your case, `init(ofType:context:options:)` is a class method of `CIDetector` in Objective-C `+ detectorOfType:context:options:`.

Such convenience initializers are not available in subclasses. It's a natural conclusion based on the fact that such factory method of a class always creates an instance of the class, it cannot create an instance of the subclass you defined.

So, if you want to provide another convenience initializer utilizing a convenience initializer based on Class Factory Method, you may need an extension.

```
extension CIDetector {

    convenience init?(rectDetectorWithAspectRatio aspectRatio: Float) {
        let options: [String : Any] = [CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh,
                                       CIDetectorAspectRatio : NSNumber(value: aspectRatio)]
        self.init(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: options)
    }

}
```

---

By the way, the diagnostics messages are seemingly completely broken from the programmers' side using Swift. You can send a [Bug Report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) about it.